# PHP Array organization

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a well-better formated list of information.

Basically what I have right now is a multi dimensional array that has multiple entries in it with different data.

If I would do foreach $bigarray, I would get something like this:

```
 array(
    "id" => 1,
    "company" => "bar",
    "advertisment" => "Selling X",
    "user_id" => "200",
    "uri" => "bbbbbbxa"
);

 array(
        "id" => 2,
        "company" => "bar",
        "advertisment" => "Selling ABC",
        "user_id" => "200",
        "uri" => "xxxaaaa"
    );

 array(
        "id" => 3,
        "company" => "CROMUS",
        "advertisment" => "Selling BBB",
        "user_id" => "222",
       "uri" => "bsaxxaa"
    );
```

** notice the same user_id and company name **

** I want a unique list of companies with ads corresponding to it **

## From the above I would get 3 'squares' of data like this:

- Company Name
- Advertisment Title

================

- Same Company Name
- Same advertisment title

================

- Different Company Name
- Different advertisment title

=========================

but I would want to get:

=========================

- Company Name
- **first advertisment title**
- **second advertisment title**
- ** so on if any other entries with same user_id are found **

=========================

- Different Company Name

  - Different Advertisment

=========================

So basically I would want array 1 to add somehow to array 0 so when I echo in the foreach($bigarray as $post), I go something like

```
echo $post['advertisment'].' '.$post['uri']
echo $post['advertisment_2'].' '.$post['uri2']
```

Note: I might have more than 2 values , I might have 6 ads on the same company and I basically want to organise them by the id (the top one would be the newest)

Until now I did something like this just to realise i took the wrong approach:

```
foreach($latest->posts as $key => $post) {
    if(in_array($post->user_id,$iduri)){
        array_push($iduri, $post->user_id);
    }
    if(in_array($post->user_id,$iduri)) {
        array_push($cuie,$post->title);
        array_push($urix,$post->uri);
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($cuie); $i++) { 
            echo $cuie[i];
            echo $urix[i];
        }  
    } // end if in array
} //end foreach
```

Comment: you could have an array of company users, rather than an array of users with company id

Comment: sidenote: this may be better for code review SE ?

Comment: One method assuming an unsorted input array. Tested, commented code: http://codepad.org/uhBrUJMS. Old version of PHP. You will need to rewrite it anyway.